# Different outputs in online gdb compiler and vs code

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdXzR.png)

code--

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, a, b, c = 0;
    cout << "Enter the number" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        a = pow(10, I);
        b = 10 * ((x % a) - c) / a;
        cout << b;
        c = x % a;
    }
}
```

The code is written to reverse the numbers but for 1024 vs code shows 04301000 and onlinegdb shows 04201000.

Comment: you say that the code is supposed to reverse the numbers. For 1024 is the expected output 4201?

Comment: Please explain the magic number "7".

Comment: The float-taking and float returning `pow()` function is risky for integer handling. It can easily cause unreliable results, because floats are broken for integer things, as you probably know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923249/unusual-output-from-pow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522223/pow-function-giving-wrong-answer

Comment: What is the expected output for 1024?

Comment: the expected output was the one shown by onlinegdb compiler.

Comment: i took 7 as a random integer so that upto 7 digits number gets reversed.

Comment: If the pow() function is unreliable what else can I use for exponential function.

Comment: Implement your own pow function or simply use a for loop to find power.

Comment: `I` is undefined

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `pow`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 0, y = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    while (x > 0) {
        y = 10 * y + (x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

Or if you don't want to remember the result and just print it, like the original:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    while (x > 0) {
        std::cout << x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my main concern was why is the output different in VS code and onlinegdb compiler.